# Automl vs hand trained tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, image-recognition, image-classification, automl, google-cloud-automl

How Automl works internally? and Automl vs custom Tensorflow image classification, which one is efficient?

Trained Automl image classification model with 86% accuracy, and looking for some more improvement so looking for alternative options. can hand trained tf model help us here ?

Comment: surely you can find better results than AutoML, depends on your knowledge however... and about how it works, there are tons of paper explaining it, but in the most naive way, it does an """optimized""" grid search over all possible combinations